# How to make bot status say member count for all the servers that its in (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Sorry for the long title. I want my bot to tell me how many members that my bot is in a server with in the bot's status. In other words, I want my bot's statues to say `Watching [member count] people and [server count] servers`, but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Potato Cat is ready :D')
    await client.change_presence(
        activity=discord.Activity(
            type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
            name=f'{len(client.guilds)} servers and {len(client.members)} people'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of servers:

```py
servers = len(client.guilds)
```

To get the number of members:

```py
members = 0
for guild in client.guilds:
    members += guild.member_count - 1    # I've added a '-1' because guild.member_count includes all users and bots including your own bot
```

So, your `on_ready()` event would look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Potato Cat is ready :D')

    servers = len(client.guilds)
    members = 0
    for guild in client.guilds:
        members += guild.member_count - 1

    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(
        type = discord.ActivityType.watching,
        name = f'{servers} servers and {members} members'
    ))
```

Comment: wait a second OMG ITS U :O




hi

Answer (score 1):

it is changed to [client.change_presence](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence)

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f'{len(client.guilds)} servers and {len(client.members)} people')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
   client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Potato Cat is ready :D')
    client.loop.create_task(status_task())
    

async def status_task():
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(
            activity=discord.Activity(
                type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
                name=f'Prefix: {prefix} | {len(bot.guilds)} server'),
            status=discord.Status.online)
        await asyncio.sleep(1800)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).