# Discord Bot Status, How to "Watching %100% Member"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

i have a discord Bot, and the status of the discord bot is "Watching Members".
(Screenshot: http://prnt.sc/12kkl2c) [schaut = watching]

But i want a member counter in the status, like "**Watching Members: 100**".
My Code:

````
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Members:"))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Members:"))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)```

What do i need to change in my code?
````

Comment: I think it would be easier this way:,
`await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Members:" + str(discord.Status.online)))`
And what type is `discord.Status.online` ? A number?

Comment: Hello, if i replace the code with yours then the status is: "Watching Members:online".

Comment: discord.Status.online is the status of the bot, (online, idle, do not disturb)

Comment: Oh, sorry I got something wrong. Maybe I have seen something wrong, but your current code does not include the member counting, right? Then replace my "discord.Status.online" with a function to get the member count. Or write your own function if you want to sum up all user amounts on all servers

Comment: Im new to python and i didnt find any tutorial how to do this since 2 days, i would appreciate if you could help me with that on discord, i dont know how to do this function.

Comment: You probably want to sum up all the user counts from all servers right? Maybe check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621353/how-to-make-bot-status-say-member-count-for-all-the-servers-that-its-in-discord

Comment: yes thats what i want, thanks, let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code a bit like this:
Get all members from all servers ([How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621353/how-to-make-bot-status-say-member-count-for-all-the-servers-that-its-in-discord))
Then do this:

```py
await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Members:" + str(totalMembers)))
```